# this method is supposed to display only the reporting period within a particular selected financial year that has same fields

Tags: input, types, syntax, integer, odoo

For clarity here is the code:

```
class ProgrammeLinking(models.Model):
    _name = 'mis.programme.linking'
    _description = 'linking and allocations'
    _rec_name = "financial_year_id"
   

    financial_year_id = fields.Many2one('res.financial.year',string='Financial Year')
    

    output_indicator_id = fields.Many2one('mis.output.indicator',string='APP Output indicator', store=True)
    allowed_output_indicator_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'mis.output.indicator', 
        compute="_compute_allowed_output_indicator_ids"
    )
    reporting_period_id = fields.Many2one('mis.create.link.national.app', string='Reporting Period')
    allowed_reporting_period_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'mis.create.link.national.app',
        compute="_compute_allowed_reporting_period_ids"
    )


     def _get_current_fy_programme_linking(self):
        for rec in self:
            return self.env['mis.create.link.national.app'].search([
                ('financial_year_id','=', rec.financial_year_id.id)
            ])


       @api.depends('outcome_id')
       def _compute_allowed_output_indicator_ids(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.outcome_id:
                fy_linkings = self._get_current_fy_programme_linking()
                output = fy_linkings \
                    .filtered(lambda l: l.outcome_id.id == rec.outcome_id.id) \
                    .mapped('output_indicator_id')
                _logger.info(f"Filtered ou {output}")
                rec.allowed_output_indicator_ids = output
            else:
                rec.allowed_output_indicator_ids = False

    
    @api.depends('output_indicator_id')
    def _compute_allowed_reporting_period_ids(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.output_indicator_id:
                fy_linkings = self._get_current_fy_programme_linking()
                period = fy_linkings \
                    .filtered(lambda l: l.output_indicator_id.id == rec.output_indicator_id.id) \
                    .mapped('reporting_period')
                _logger.info(f"Filtered periods {period}")
                rec.allowed_reporting_period_ids = period
            else:
                rec.allowed_reporting_period_ids = False
```

the in the view:

```
<field name="allowed_output_indicator_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="output_indicator_id" required="1" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" domain="[('id','in', allowed_output_indicator_ids)]"/>

<field name="allowed_reporting_period_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="reporting_period_id" required="1" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" domain="[('id','in', allowed_reporting_period_ids)]"/>
```

Now the error I am getting when I click on the field "reporting_period_id"
and the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\odoo14\server\odoo\http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\odoo14\server\odoo\http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "quarterly"
LINE 1: ...p" WHERE ("mis_create_link_national_app"."id" in ('quarterly...
                                                             ^
```

the reporting period is a Selection field in the class I am searching and the value of it in the selected financial year is "quarterly" but I am getting this error.

I'd appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "quarterly"
LINE 1: ...p" WHERE ("mis_create_link_national_app"."id" in ('quarterly...
```

seems not to be directly linked to the code you have provided, because the error concerns:

```
mis_create_link_national_app.id
```

which is an integer and the sql operation :

```
 IN
```

and an integer can t be IN a list of STRING (in your case: 'quaterly')

**Solution**:
replacing 'quaterly' by its corresponding record-id (you might probably just append **.id** after the fieldname in your query)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by [.mapped('reporting_period')](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.mapped), which will return a list of reporting periods:

```
['quarterly', ...]
```

Then Odoo will fail to set/fetch the value of the `allowed_reporting_period_ids` field

To fix this issue, you can simply remove `mapped` (Odoo accepts to [assign a recordset](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/account/models/account_move.py#L528) to a field)